# Did something wrong with my code, the value for date is return 1970-01-01 in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

form :

```
<div class="form-group has-success">
<label for="sendingdate" class="control-label">Sending Date (YYYY-MM-DD)</label>
<div class="col-10">
<input class="form-control" type="date" value="<?php echo date("Y-m-d");?>" id="sendingdate">
/div>
</div>
```

php :

```
$sendingdate = strtotime($_POST['sendingdate']);
$sendingdate = date("Y-m-d", $sendingdate);

$query = "INSERT INTO form (`Sending_Date`) VALUES('$sendingdate')";
```

mysql :

[image]

Comment: you should set current date for that input control

Comment: Your form doesn't have <form></form> tags. Moreover, you doesn't have a submit button, and after all, the input containing your date doesn't have name="sendingdate".

Comment: thanks correcting me for php... have a nice day ^^)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add name attribute to your html input field **(Example - name="sendingdate" )**.

```
<input class="form-control" type="date" value="<?php echo date("Y-m-d");?>" id="sendingdate" name="sendingdate">
```

Then you can get its value in php by

```
$sendingdate = strtotime($_POST['sendingdate']);
```

Comment: thanks a lot.. my mistake forgot to write name="sendingdate" .. have a nice day ^^)

Comment: please upvote and accept my answer if its helpful for you :) .

Answer (score 0):

You need to give name to input tag

```
<div class="form-group has-success">
     <label for="sendingdate" class="control-label">Sending Date (YYYY-MM-DD)</label>
    <div class="col-10">
        <input class="form-control" name="sendingdate" type="date" value="<?php echo date("Y-m-d");?>" id="sendingdate" />
    </div>
```

Comment: thanks... shubham715 already told me the mistake.. have a nice day ^^)